# Immediate function with another function call Javascript

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm reading Javascript Ninja from John Resig, and there is this one concept mentioned in Memoization chapter which I can't figure out how it works. And I'm having trouble finding an explanation on Google. So, here is the example from the book.

```
  Function.prototype.memoized = function(key){
    this._values = this._values || {};
    return this._values[key] !== undefined ?
      this._values[key] :
      this._values[key] = this.apply(this, arguments);
  };
Function.prototype.memoize = function(){
    var fn = this;                        
    return function(){                           
      return fn.memoized.apply( fn, arguments );
    };
  };
  var isPrime = (function(num) {
    var prime = num != 1;
    for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return prime;
  }).memoize(); // I don't understand how this works
```

Now, I understand how closure works in this example, and I understand prototypes in general, but I don't understand how this `(function expression).memoize()` part works? I see that memoize returns a function, and that function (I presume) is added to `isPrime`, but how does this `(function expression)` get called, or how does it fit in as part of isPrime method? So, when I call `isPrime(17)`, what is executed first?

Edit:
Ok, I'm now confused from all the commants, so here is how I now see it.

- First: When `(function(num){....}).memoize()` gets called, the anonymous function expression `(function(num){...})` is represented as `this` in the memoize function and assigned to fn.
- Second: Inside memoize an anonymous function is returned which holds `fn` via a closure. That returned anonymous function is assigned to `isPrime`
- Third: When we call `isPrime(17)`, actually what is called is `fn.memoized.apply(fn, attributes)`, and inside memoized `this` (the context) represents fn which is a reference to the anonymous function (function(num{...})). And this part: `this.apply(this, arguments)` executes that anonymous function (function(num) {...})

  Which makes sense, first a check needs to be made if the number is cached, and if not check if it is prime and put it in the cache.

Comment: The function expression becomes the `this` value inside the `memoize` method.

Comment: Remembers that things inside () get called straight away. Much like an inline if statement like `(isTrue === true) ? "":"" ;` Whereby the expression `(isTrue === true) ? is evaluated at run time.

Comment: This means that (function(){return true}) will be called at run time and you do not need to invoke it.

Comment: Aha! So it actually gets called in this part, this._values[key] = this.apply(this, arguments); ?

Comment: No it gets called when you set `var isPrime = (function(){})`.

`this.apply()` is a native function

Comment: I May have explained it wrong. things inside () where () is not a parenthesis for a function, get called straight away. Like your `var isPrime = (function(){})`

Comment: To third: You're almost right. The thunk is called (a function without any arguments). This thunk invokes `fn.memoized.apply` and returns the result of this invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following happens:

- the `Function` prototype is extended with two methods `memoized` and `memoize` (however, extending native prototypes isn't recommended)
- Before the function expression `(function(num)...` is assigned to `isPrime` `memoize` of the Function prototype is invoked
- inside `memoize` `this` is automatically bound to the object the method is called on (the function object in this case). So `this` refers to the anonymous function, which later is assigned to `isPrime`. Finally a thunk `return function(){...` is returned to defer the execution.
- when this thunk is eventually invoked, it uses `apply` to pass an arbitrary number of arguments to `memoized` (note that the first argument provided to `memoized` is used as a key for the memoizing cache)

I consider this implementation ugly, because amongst other things it obscures the fact that not the original anonymous function is assigned to `isPrime`, but the thunk that wraps it.

I'm not sure if `isPrime` (or the anonymous function expression) is an IIFE, since merely the method of its prototype is called immediately, not the function itself.

Comment: Ok, I'm now confused from all the commants, so here is how I now see it.

Comment: @pord911 I think that this memoize ES5 implementation is really ugly and overcomplicated. I guess it is only for the purpose of studying.

Comment: True, but as I see it he's pulling this from proffesional code, that is Prototype framework, I guess? So, one could end up working with this kind of code implementations. Good thing is, one can see what can actually be done with Javascript.

Comment: @pord911 I expended my answer by an explanation why I consider this implementation bad.